# $(this).append() not working in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

When I try to append in angularjs, I got an error like

> jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>
> 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

The line I got error was

```
  $(this).append(stringDir);
```

Where `stringDir` is the `p` element. I added `context:this` to my ajax call 
  to fix the error, but still showing the error.

```
    var app = angular.module('fileApp', []);

    app.controller('fileController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.getFile = function(event) {
        $scope.status = $scope.clickStatus;
        if($scope.status=="0" ) {   
            $scope.clickStatus = "1";
            $scope.arrowStatus = "1";

            $scope.data = {
               path : $scope.current_directory
            };  

            $(this).find($(".arrow ")).removeClass('fa fa-caret-right').addClass('fa fa-caret-down');

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/cfc/file.cfc?method=show",
                dataType : 'JSON',
                data : { path : $(this).attr('current_directory') },    
                context :this,  
                success:function(response) {
                var i=0;
                    if(response) {
                        var stringFile='';
                        var stringDir = '';
                        for(i=0; i< response.DATA.length;i++){
                            var val=(response.DATA[i]);
                            if(val[2]==="Dir"){
                                var newPath = val[6]+"\\"+val[0];
                                console.log(newPath);
                                stringDir += '<p class="dirClass" style="margin-left:15px" current_directory="'+newPath+'"  ><span ><i class="fa fa-caret-right arrow"></i></span><span> <i class="fa fa-folder-open folder_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>'  + val[0]+'</p>';
                            }
                            else{
                                var newPath = val[6]+"\\"+val[0];
                                stringFile += '<p class="fileClass " style="margin-left:18px" current_directory="'+newPath+'"><i class="fa fa-file file_icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>  '+ val[0] +'</p>';
                            }
                        }  
                        $(this).append($(stringDir)); 
                        $(this).append($(stringFile));   
                    }
                },
                error:function (data){
                console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

   });

 HTML

<body ng-app="fileApp" ng-controller="fileController" >
<div class="row left_row_content_drive" id ="left_row_content_drive">
<div class="localdisc_d_click" id="container_id" >
<p class="dirClass" ng-init = "current_directory= 'D:\projects' 
;clickStatus = '0' ;arrowStatus= '0' " ><i class="fa fa-hdd-o 
drive_icon"  aria-hidden="true" ng-click="getFile()"></i> Local Disc D 
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: i think `this` is not refering to a DOM element

Comment: Could you please provide context code where you use $(this)?

Comment: You used in Controller/Component or in Service? Which version of Angular you using?

Comment: Yes I also think like that, but how can I fix this? instead of 'this' what can I use?

Comment: Please provide complete code how's and where you are using `$(this)`. Corresponding rendered html will also very good. Add it in your question

Comment: I am using Angularjs 1.

Comment: @Aash - By "context code," we mean provide us with more lines of code before and after the line you've provided. You can do so by **Editing** your question. For example `$(this)` refers to nothing within a `.done()` AJAX callback, within a regular `for` loop, and lots of scenarios. We can't tell you what's wrong without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Please provide your Controller/Service and corresponding markup as well. It will help people provide you suitable answer.

Comment: Have you tried by $(this).append($(stringDir)); ? Because 'stringDir' is just a string until you wrap up with $().

Comment: @Hanif Yes I tried, but still getting the error.

Comment: @Aash Please updated your question post by adding from where you clicking and complete JS file or code where you wrote.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Yes I edited and added the full code.

Comment: @Hanif I added the code.

Comment: The this you are using is controller instance not dom

Comment: where is this getfile called

Comment: Inside angular controller function 'this' not a element where you trying add the another element. So add the markup as well where you wanna add html.

Comment: Your code is really messed up and you are implementing wrongly, avoid using jquery in angular code.

Comment: if you want a better answer you will have to provide the html and your requirement

Comment: try replacing the this with the container div of whatever you are trying to append to.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use this inside an ajax success callback block. Instead create a variable for the element before the ajax call and then refer to that variable to access that element inside the success callback. Something like below

```
 var element = this; //Hold the element in 'element' variable


   //Your ajax call
    $.ajax({
       url: "Any Url",
       success: function(response){
     if (response) {
      var stringFile = '';
      var stringDir = '';
      for (i = 0; i < response.DATA.length; i++) {
        var val = (response.DATA[i]);
        if (val[2] === "Dir") {
          var newPath = val[6] + "\\" + val[0];
          console.log(newPath);
          stringDir += '<p class="dirClass" style="margin-left:15px" 
          current_directory = "'+newPath+'" > < span > < i class =
            "fa fa-caret-right arrow" >
            <
            /i></span > < span > < i class =
            "fa fa-folder-open folder_icon"
          aria -
            hidden = "true" > < /i></span > '  + val[0]+' < /p>';
        } else {
          var newPath = val[6] + "\\" + val[0];
          stringFile += '<p class="fileClass " style="margin-left:18px" 
          current_directory = "'+newPath+'" > < i class =
            "fa fa-file file_icon"
          aria -
            hidden = "true" > < /i>  '+ val[0] +'</p > ';
        }
      }
      $(element).append(stringDir);
      $(element).append(stringFile);
    }
       }

    })
```

Comment: 'this' in that case not a element. So I don't think it will work.

Comment: this need to be an element because he's using jquery's append.

Comment: from where he will get that element @shridhar you are still using this of controller

Answer (score -1):

You're right here 'this' is the controller, sorry! my mistake, but if you replace 'this' with the element reference then this code will run